# Not allowed to load local resource when opening chrome:// UI page from a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a MV2 Chrome extension that on the popup page I added a "Shortcut" link so that user can access `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` by clicking it.

However, after upgrading to MV3, the link doesn't work.

[image]

Should I simply remove this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by opening the page programmatically.

1. add some suitable selector to the link (popup html):

```html
<a href="#" id="commands-link">Configure Commands</a>
```

2. add an event listener to open the shortcuts page (in popup script):

```js
// get the DOM node
const link = document.getElementById("commands-link");

// add click event handler that opens the shortcuts page
link.addEventListener('click', () => chrome.tabs.create({
    url: "chrome://extensions/configureCommands"
}));
```

Comment: thanks but why does the first way do any harm to the chrome ecosystem? Just wondering why Google makes it. Do you have any clue?c

Comment: I don't have any official answer, but I suspect in handling different protocols, it probably defaults to allowing only specific ones (rather than blocking specific ones) and chrome-protocol is not on this allowed list.